# How to use curl behind a McAfee Web Gateway?

Tags: macos, terminal

`curl` seems to get some URLs just fine, while others get blocked with a response that indicates authentication is required and a valid cookie is missing.

I can download the same URL in Chrome. No proxy is configured in Chrome.

Comment: Can we get an example URL that works fine in Chrome but not curl?

Comment: Here's a relevant [link.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35983/malicious-links-that-respond-to-browsers-but-not-curl-or-wget)

Comment: I understand why you would ask. Sorry, but I really prefer not to expose any specific URLs. I can add that the authentication required messages come from the McAfee Web Gateway's IP address not the host from the URLs.

Comment: Have you tried getting curl to change its User-Agent string? (eg curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36' [http://example.com](http://example.com/))  Some sites block certain User Agent strings, so it's always worth a try.

Comment: @AdamThompson Yes, but without success. Great suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've learned browsing StackOverflow the last few minutes, there are a few ways to try check if someone is using curl rather than a browser. Common ways include checking if the "browser" has javascript support, checking the user-agent and looking for missing request fields.

I attempted to use curl to access http://yahoo.com which returned a "Will be right back..." webpage. But, I then used wget with a user-agent borrowed from Firefox and I got the regular webpage. Try using wget to see if it makes a difference.